# How to find userID after login as root using pmksh?

Tags: users, quest-privilege-access

I am trying to gather the username of the actual person logged in the server instead of just showing root. After entering [pmksh](http://documents.software.dell.com/privilege-manager-for-unix/6.0/administrators-guide/privilege-manager-programs/pmksh), the prompt changes to root@hostname.

When I do `echo $USER` the result is `root`.

Instead I want to find the actual userid the person used to log in. This will allow me to include user id in the notification email instead of default root name.

OS: Solaris 5.10
Shell: Korn shell

Comment: your config may be running "keepenv" with a limited set of environment variables. Try logging in and running `env` to see if there is any evidence of your original login.

Comment: I don't have a solaris to try it on but can you match `tty` to `last`? On Debian I can do this `user_tty=\`tty | grep -o 'pts\/[0-9]\+'\`; last | grep "still logged in" | grep $user_tty` and yes I know that is the ugliest pipeline ever...

Comment: Try `whoami` and `who am i`.

Comment: How do you become root? Is that what the `pmksh` command does? I can't find any such command on Solaris.

Comment: @Scott who am i output is root. Its not showing the actual user_id

Comment: @Gilles pmksh is a quest previlage manager for UNIX. It's not a command http://us-downloads.quest.com/Repository/support.quest.com/Privilege%20Manager%20for%20Unix/5.1.1/Documentation/Privilege%20Manager_5.1.1_ReleaseNotes.htm

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem: The actual user ID was stored in environment variable  `$ORIG_USER`.
This works in our environment; YMMV.